# Не могу избавиться от юникода в json.dumps

Tags: python, json, unicode

```
def print_json(limit, soup):
    feed = html.unescape(soup.title.text)
    dict_json = {feed: {}}
    items = soup.findAll('item')
    for i in items:
        dict_json[feed] = {'Title': html.unescape(i.title.text), 'Date': html.unescape(i.pubDate.text),
                           'Link': html.unescape(i.link.text)}
    print(json.dumps(dict_json, indent=4))
```

При запуске программы полуаю

```
{
    "TUT.BY: \u041d\u043e\u0432\u043e\u0441\u0442\u0438 \u0422\u0423\u0422 - \u0413\u043b\u0430\u0432\u043d\u044b\u0435 \u043d\u043e\u0432\u043e\u0441\u0442\u0438": {
        "Title": "\u0421 \u041b\u0435\u043d\u0438\u043d\u044b\u043c \u0432 \u0441\u0435\u0440\u0434\u0446\u0435 \u0438 \u0433\u0432\u043e\u0437\u0434\u0438\u043a\u0430\u043c\u0438 \u0432 \u0440\u0443\u043a\u0430\u0445. \u041a\u0430\u043a \u0432 \u041c\u0438\u043d\u0441\u043a\u0435 \u043e\u0442\u043c\u0435\u0442\u0438\u043b\u0438 \u0433\u043e\u0434\u043e\u0432\u0449\u0438\u043d\u0443 \u041e\u043a\u0442\u044f\u0431\u0440\u044c\u0441\u043a\u043e\u0439 \u0440\u0435\u0432\u043e\u043b\u044e\u0446\u0438\u0438",
        "Date": "Thu, 07 Nov 2019 15:36:00 +0300",
        "Link": "https://news.tut.by/economics/660484.html?utm_campaign=news-feed&utm_medium=rss&utm_source=rss-news"
    }
}
```

Хотя, например, заголовок должен быть "TUT.BY: Новости ТУТ - Главные новости"
Почему так выходит, что какие-то строки выходят нормальными, а какие-то нет?

Comment: используйте параметр `json.dumps(..., ensure_ascii=False)`

Comment: @MaxU Не сработало

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, полный код, воспроизводящий проблему.

Comment: @MaxU Изначально поставил True, либо вы изначально не так написали, либо я уже поплыл)

Comment: @dhvcc, это я изначально случайно написал `ensure_ascii=True` - виной тому лень - скопировал из Docstring ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция [json.dumps(obj, ..., ensure_ascii=True, ...)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps) по умолчанию заменяет все "не ASCII" символы на соответствующие юникодные символы с использованием unicode номера. Кириллические символы не принадлежат ASCII диапазону и будут заменены на `"\u<number>"` представление.

Чтобы запретить данную замену укажите явно параметр `ensure_ascii=False`

Comment: С False сработало, спасибо